# web api TypeConverter no se ejecuta

Tags: c#, api, web

Estoy haciendo mi primera web api y tengo el sgte controlador:

```
 // POST api/Recipes
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] RecipeModel newRecipe)
    {
        if (newRecipe != null)
        {
            using (var container = Db4oEmbedded.OpenFile(Db4oEmbedded.NewConfiguration(), DbPath))
                try
                {
                    var mayBeRecipe = (from RecipeModel recipe in container
                                       where recipe.GetHashCode() == newRecipe.GetHashCode()
                                       select recipe).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (mayBeRecipe == null)
                        container.Store(newRecipe);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(e);
                }
        }

    }
```

Para enviar newRecipe como parametro tengo además un type converter:

```
 public class RecipeTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return true;

        //   return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        var newRecipe = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RecipeModel>(value as string);

        return newRecipe;
    }
}
```

El problema que tengo es que pruebo la api utilizando Postman, enviandole 
un RecipeModel en el body y el  RecipeTypeConverter  no se ejecuta (pongo un punto de interrupcion en el metodo ConvertFrom)

El json es el sgte:

```
{ "Name":"pure patata",

   "Ingredients": [
       {
           "Name":"patata"
       },
       {
           "Name":"sal"
       } 
   ],

   "Yield":4,

   "Steps":"mezclarlo todo"
}
```

Haber si me podeis echar una mano porque llevo muchisimo tiempo investigando que ocurre.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que registrar el [`TypeConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) como atributo en el action:

```
[HttpPost]
[TypeConverter(typeof(RecipeTypeConverter))]
public void Post([FromBody] RecipeModel newRecipe)
{
//...
```

Comment: Sí, me faltaba registrarlo. No obstante continúa el mismo problema.